# Rail service from London to Brussels on Boxing Day?

Tags: trains, london, brussels, christmas

I need to know If there are some rail service from London to Brussels on Boxing Day. I´d like to get more info about that

Comment: Have you tried booking a ticket for that date on Eurostar's website and seeing whether it comes up with any departures?

Comment: [Boxing Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_Day) = December 26.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on 26 December 2017 there are Eurostar trains running.
You can already buy tickets on the [Eurostar website.](https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en)
There is a Live Chat option on the site, so you can ask your questions if you do not want to believe the online information.

As the time tables change early in December I could not double check for you.
(The Eurostar site only gave afternoon and evening departures, which might well be true for the day but would be unusual for a normal day of service.)